# Missing the location, history and match properties when combining custom props with RouteComponentProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-v4

I have a component handling routing, and the I am using the react-router properties: 'history, match, location'. I mapped my functional component as receiving `IRoute` as props and combined it with RouteComponentProps in order to have access to 'history, match, location';

```
const PrivateRoute: FC<IRoute & RouteComponentProps> = ({ component: Component, roles, isAuthenticated, user, ...rest }) => (

);
```

This is my route code.

```
const routes: IRoute[] = [
{
    path     : '/',
    exact    : true,
    auth     : false,
    component: Home
},
]
```

And this is my interface code.

```
 export interface IRoute extends RouteComponentProps {
path     : string;
exact    : boolean;
auth     : boolean;
component: React.ElementType;
roles   ?: string[];
 }
```

When trying to initialize my PrivateRoute component I get in my terminal:

```
TS2739: Type '{ path: string; exact: boolean; auth: boolean; component: ElementType<any>; roles?: string[] | undefined; key: number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly<Pick<IRoute & IAuthState & RouteComponentProps<{}, StaticContext, any>, "path" | "location" | "history" | "match" | "staticContext" | "component" | "exact" | "auth" | "roles">>': location, history, match
```

I am new to typescript so if anyone can please explain to me what I am doing wrong it would be very appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

This may be a duplicate of this question: [How to test a React component with RouteComponentProps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46927392/how-to-test-a-react-component-with-routecomponentprops)

I liked this answer the best due to the simple mocking approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60765926/2212881

it shows how to mock the RouteComponentProps and use a spread operator to pass it into your component.

something similar to:

```
const routeComponentPropsMock = {
  history: {} as any,
  location: {} as any,
  match: {} as any,
}

{ component: Component, roles, isAuthenticated, user, ...rest, ...routeComponentPropsMock  }
```